# Find all products produced by 2 unique elements of an array (python)

Tags: python, arrays, loops

How do you determine the product/sum/difference/division of all the numbers in an array in python?
For example for multiplication:

```
array=[1,2,3,4]
```

output will just be 1*2, 1*3, 1*4, 2*3, 2*4, 3*4:

```
[2,3,4,6,8,12]
```

I understand how "for" and "while" loops work but have been unable to figure out the solution-- how do I find every unique set of 2 variables in an array of len(array) variables? After I do that I can just do the corresponding multiplication/division/subtraction/etc.

At best all I could make was the product of an array:

```
array=[1,2,3]
product = 1
for i in array:
    product *= i
print product
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [i * j for i, j in combinations(array, 2)]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
```

Comment: Ha!  Mine is 1 line shorter - LOL ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters Pfft. Mine has links. Noob :)

Comment: reading the code of def combinations, there is 0 chance i would have ever thought of that

Comment: @NoobCoder That's why itertools is there for you :)

Answer (score 6):

Here you go.  It's easy when you know the tricks ;-)

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> [a*b for a, b in combinations([1,2,3,4], 2)]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
```

Comment: Sadly, the answer to *find all the products* isn't `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 4):

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you are still interested in the loop based solution.

```
result = []
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
        result.append(array[i] * array[j])
print result
```

This can be written with list comprehension, like this

```
print [array[i] * array[j] for i in range(len(array)) for j in range(i + 1, len(array))]
```

Answer (score 4):

USE ALL THE ITERTOOLS!

```
>>> from itertools import starmap, combinations as combos
>>> from operator import mul
>>> products = starmap(mul, combos([1,2,3,4], 2))
>>> list(products)
[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
```

Ok, not ALL, but MOAR.